# [ROS2] ros2 doctor: UserWarning: <PKG> has been updated to a new version

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

i had run `ros2 doctor` on my PC and got following output:

```
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: joint_state_controller has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.1 < required: 0.2.0
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: ament_index_python has been updated to a new version. local: 1.0.1 < required: 1.0.2
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: domain_coordinator has been updated to a new version. local: 0.9.0 < required: 0.9.1
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: ros2controlcli has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.2 < required: 0.1.6
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: control_msgs has been updated to a new version. local: 2.4.1 < required: 2.5.0
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: controller_interface has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.2 < required: 0.1.6
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: hardware_interface has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.2 < required: 0.1.6
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: velocity_controllers has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.1 < required: 0.2.0
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: ament_cmake_ros has been updated to a new version. local: 0.9.0 < required: 0.9.1
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: ros2_control has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.2 < required: 0.1.6
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: controller_manager_msgs has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.2 < required: 0.1.6
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: rqt_gui has been updated to a new version. local: 1.0.6 < required: 1.0.7
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: diagnostic_updater has been updated to a new version. local: 2.0.4 < required: 2.0.6
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: rqt_py_common has been updated to a new version. local: 1.0.6 < required: 1.0.7
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: rqt_gui_cpp has been updated to a new version. local: 1.0.6 < required: 1.0.7
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: controller_manager has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.2 < required: 0.1.6
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: robot_state_publisher has been updated to a new version. local: 2.4.1 < required: 2.4.2
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: ament_index_cpp has been updated to a new version. local: 1.0.1 < required: 1.0.2
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: forward_command_controller has been updated to a new version. local: 0.1.1 < required: 0.2.0
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: libyaml_vendor has been updated to a new version. local: 1.0.2 < required: 1.0.3
/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2doctor/api/package.py: 112: UserWarning: rqt_gui_py has been updated to a new version. local: 1.0.6 < required: 1.0.7
```

I have tried to update my system with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` but it gives me that all packages are up to date.

I found this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/368167/how-to-update-a-ros2-package/) but this did not update my python packages.

How can i update these packages or or do I have to wait for a new Foxy update.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371889/%5Bros2%5D-ros2-doctor:-userwarning:-%3Cpkg%3E-has-been-updated-to-a-new-version/) by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2021-02-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current versions of the ROS2 packages will sync monthly to the rosdistro Repo. After that a update with `apt update` can be done.

See the latest sync and status on [ROS Discourse](https://discourse.ros.org/c/release/foxy/)

---

Originally posted by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) with karma: 219 on 2021-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1